# Rails: Has_many relationship and dynamic form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models in my project: Invoice and InvoicePosition. Invoice has many InvoicePositions. I want to create a form for new invoice but with additional fields to create also invoice positions in same time. I want to make in dynamically, i mean i want to add more invoice positions by adding new fields with javascript. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Look up https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: this is exactly what i needed, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using nested model forms, e.g. `accept_nested_attributes_for :invoice_position`. You can find more information about it [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised). The dynamic part is achieved through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use [simple_form_for](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem it has options for associations